# I am having trouble with a random math problem generator

Tags: python

I think I have everything down except for the part that verifies if your answer is correct. The part that print "Good job" does not work and has not been giving me errors, it just does not print.

I will paste the code:

```
import random
random_number1 = random.randrange(1,100)
random_number2 = random.randrange(1,100)
correct_answer = random_number1 + random_number2


print("What is ")
print(random_number1)
print("+")
print(random_number2)
guess = input("Enter answer: ")
if guess == correct_answer:
print("Good job!")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please pay attention to code formatting, especially with Python. Code as posted will produce an error because the line after `if` is not indented.

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  The integer `75` is not equal to the string `"75"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the indentation after the if statement - python requires indentation.

Also, the input function will return a string, so you need to convert it to int.

```
import random
random_number1 = random.randrange(1,100)
random_number2 = random.randrange(1,100)
correct_answer = random_number1 + random_number2


print("What is ")
print(random_number1)
print("+")
print(random_number2)
guess = input("Enter answer: ")
if int(guess) == correct_answer:
    print("Good job!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `input` in Python 3 is always a string. The result of multiplying two integers is an integer. A string is not equal to an integer: you have to convert them both to the same type, for example:

```
if int(guess) == correct_answer:
```

This does not check for correctness. Python will complain if `guess` does not represent a valid integer, so catching `ValueError` would be in order:

```
guess_str = input("Enter answer: ")
try:
    guess = int(guess_str)
    if guess == correct_answer:
        print("Good job!")
except ValueError:
    print("Hey, that's not a nice number!")
```

Comment: Why did I not realize that! ‍♂️   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to add "int" before input:
guess=int(input("Enter Answer")

Issue is, for instance if the answer is 75 and the user guess is "75" too, int 75 and str "75" are not equal. That's why it does not print "Good job!".

Answer (score 0):

Input returns a `string` and you have to convert it to `int` to compare. Also you should use `f-string` (formatting strings) to write clean code. Here is the complete answer

```py
import random

random_number1 = random.randrange(1,100)
random_number2 = random.randrange(1,100)
correct_answer = random_number1 + random_number2

# use fstrings to write clean code
print(f'What is {random_number1} + {random_number2} ')

guess = input('Enter answer: ')

try:
    if int(guess) == correct_answer:
        print('Good job !')
except ValueError:
        print('Not a valid integer')
```